# jquery ui tabs change content after .tabs() initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

**OBJECTIVE:**
How can I change content of ui tabs after it has been initialized.

See code below.Possible something after $tabs.find(content-1) etc

1. Actually My tabs have content based on json requests which then will
   be parsed and displayed as per requriement (graphs,tables etc).
2. I can not use

   tab1 method described
   in ui docs for ajax content because I need all tabs to have data
   separately and load simultaneously. Ajax method keeps replacing one
   tab data with other tab data which is not my requirement.

So ideally,

1. tabs should init with "loading .." message.
2. Then Afetr i have detected its init event , i should make say 3 different ajaxcalls , process data and whichever is completed, "loading .." message should be replace with its content.

[**My JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/U2z44/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>loading...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>loading...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>loading...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    cache: false,
});
//
$tabs.do something here
$tab. detect evet if tabs have initialized ..
then send ajax requests and append to tabs content area ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/H9MYE/4/)

Try this

I guess this is what you need

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
        cache: false,
    });
    if ($('#tabs').hasClass('ui-tabs')) { // check if tabs initilized
        $('.tab').each(function () {
            var tab = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/html/',
                success: function (data) {
                    tab.html("success"); // for demo
                }

            });

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: One question.$('.tab').each(function () { .. does this mean all ajax calls will be triggered all together ? or will it wait for one to succeed/fail and then move to next ajax call ?

Comment: if you want each of the ajax request to take one after another add async: false inside the ajax inside ie..   url: '/echo/html/', async: false,success: function (data) {
                    tab.html("success"); // for demo
                }

Comment: async: false will make the request synchronous ie on each ajax call it wait for one to succeed/fail only then next will be proceeded

Comment: I want All ajaxs requests to trigger at once and which ever is completed should append/repalce its content. One ajax request should not depend on pther to finish. So is your code valid for this situation ?

Comment: Ok so the above will do , It send ajax request sequentially but do not wait for  the response, response is the order first come first , which response come first it will be displayed